# Slow reading of cache file in php

Tags: php, performance, caching, file-read

I have a script that generates a very github-gist like code snip with code highlighting.

Because the highlighting take a bit to render long files, I store them as cache files on the server, and if a cache file exists, I use file_get_contents to grab it and spit it out.

I just published one of my longer snips (about 257K worth of code) and the cache file is taking just over a full second to load.

This seems like a very long time for that size of a file. I just checked and 50K files are taking about .4 to .5 seconds.

Any ideas on what could be causing this slow read speed?

Answer (score 1):

If you can, try to use client-side highlighting.  [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) looks good for this.

Comment: I look looked at this a while ago. It was hard to find code highlighting at the time for stuff like arduino and processing. Im using geshi, so it is pretty easy to make highlighters. Ill take a look at this again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [`readfile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) instead of `file_get_contents`? This may get you better results.

Comment: I did, and it was barely faster. Like under 5% faster.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using X-Sendfile. It's built-in in [lighttpd](http://blog.lighttpd.net/articles/2006/07/02/x-sendfile) and [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) or available as a [module for Apache](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/).

Basically you just ask the webserver to serve a custom static file, instead of loading it in memory and then sending it off.

Comment: This won't work if the file he is reading should be embedded hin other generated HTML.

Comment: Sure it won't. But you can cache the whole page (provided you don't tailor it for each user).